# NSScrollView calls drawRect on custom views for every frame

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsscrollview

I have lots of experience with iOS, but I am new to MacOS development.

I am using NSScrollView to scroll multiple instances of a custom subclass of NSView. This custom subclass has a custom `drawRect` implementation. So multiple instances of this subclass are displayed at once (can even be up to 100 instances).

Everything works fine, but when I scroll I notice that it is not doing it very smoothly. By placing an `NSLog()` statement inside the `drawRect` implementation I soon found out it is getting called **for each frame** during scrolling.

What I am used to on iOS is that `drawRect` is called once, and the contents are never redrawn unless you ask for it by calling `setNeedsDisplay`.

I want to improve the performance of my NSScrollView by not making my custom NSViews redraw lots of times during scrolling, but instead remember what was last drawn. How can it be done?

Comment: Does drawRect get called even when not scrolling? This seems normal(at least to me) My NSScrollViews do the same. It might help to move all CPU intensive code out of drawRect and just have it draw its contents.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a way to make it draw everything only once! I am now using an `NSImage` to draw everything on once. I only do this again when the model changes.

```
buffer = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:self.bounds.size];
[buffer lockFocus];
[self drawStuff];
[buffer unlockFocus];
```

After that I simply draw that image onto screen, which appears to be **way** faster.

```
- (void) drawRect:(NSRect) dirtyRect {
    [buffer drawInRect:self.bounds];
}
```

Comment: I considered this initially. I assume you don't have interactivity?

Comment: How does re-sizing work when you use an NSImage? Run into issues?

Comment: I just measured how much faster it is. The normal drawing takes 0,276ms on average, while drawing the image takes 0,096ms on average.

Comment: I don't have interactivity at this moment but I will have it in the future. I don't think it will cause a problem because I can simply update the buffer image every time I need the drawing to change.

And as for resizing... it might cause problems. I am rendering all this in an `NSPopover` at the moment so it is not easy for me to check how resizing behaves.

Comment: I think that for resizing you could implement `- (void) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:(NSSize) oldSize` to update the image buffer.

Comment: yeah, but I was wondering if the creation of the image(size) multiple times in resize(including the lock and unlock calls which block UI) could cause a potential problem. Good luck with your solution!

Answer (score 2):

It 'might' help to set `[scrollView.contentView setCopiesOnScroll:YES];` if your drawRect is very performance intensive.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately setting that property has no effect :( drawRect is still called just as often.

Comment: have you profiled your `drawRect` calls? You are doing something unnecessary if it takes more than a few milliseconds.

Comment: I just did. Each NSView takes less than 1 millisecond to render. The problem is that there are like 40 instances of this NSView visible at once.

Comment: I ran into an upper-limit of NSTextViews inside the `documentView` of the NSScrollView. I ended up rendering all of them in the documentView's drawRect significantly reducing overhead.

Comment: How did you approach rendering them all at once? Calling all drawRect's directly?

Comment: My documentView of the scrollView knew where the text had to be rendered. So now I had only 1 custom view, the document view. And used NSAttributedString's `drawInRect` to render all the strings. But depending on your NSView control, it may be complicated to implement it

Comment: I forgot. By doing the above way, I directly control what I draw and don't even bother rendering those out of view

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thanks!